# What type of hard drive connectors are these?

Tags: hard-drive

If this is a better question for something like Retrocomputing let me know and I'll post it there. I'm trying to do some data recovery for a friend on some *very* old laptops that I can't boot (power cables are long gone). I removed the hard drives thinking I'd just use my trusty SATA/IDE to USB connectors to read the drives. Much to my surprise I was greeted by not one but two different ATA connectors I'd never seen before:

[image: Seagate momentus 5400.2 ST968912A]

and this one

[image: Seagate momentus 4200.2 ST960821A]

The first is for a Seagate momentus 5400.2 ST968912A, the second is for a Seagate momentus 4200.2 ST960821A. Is there any easy way to externally mount and read the contents of of these with e.g. a modern Ubuntu laptop? I don't mind ordering some adapters if I have to. My existing external connectors look like this:

[image: IDE to USB]

You can see the molex and standard 44 pin IDE.

Comment: Looks like SAS.  Does the label on the HDDs indicated they are SATA?

Comment: @Ramhound drives themselves don't say, but as far as I can tell from [searching the model #](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03uuZTxxGm_Uvk5WepaaN4Vi9O3Aw%3A1605806812924&ei=3Kq2X9PoN82GtQatwqiICA&q=seagate+momentus+5400.2+st96812a+60gb&oq=seagate+momentus+5400.2+st96812a+60gb&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQBxAeOgQIABBHUJQdWJQdYNMfaABwAngAgAFniAFnkgEDMC4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBBMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjTxqXFkI_tAhVNQ80KHS0hCoEQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) the magic 8ball says not SATA. Also these are very old (like 15-20 years old) consumer-grade laptops, would it use SAS?

Comment: Is the connector on the HDD maybe removable? Often you'll find regular IDE pins underneath.

Comment: @Ramhound: That's way too many pins for SAS. Traditional _parallel_ SCSI is more likely, though I don't know if anyone other than Apple used that in laptops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many laptops used to have proprietary ATA connectors that might not necessarily have a specific name other than "FooManufacturer laptop ATA connector", so the question cannot be easily answered without knowing the manufacturer (and often the model – e.g. IBM alone had a large variety).

Most of those connectors, however, are actually just adapters that can be carefully removed, revealing a more standard 44-pin "laptop ATA" connector underneath.

(But note that these are still not the same as desktop 40-pin ATA connectors – to quote Wikipedia, "The pins are closer together and the connector is physically smaller than the 40-pin connector. The extra pins carry power.")

Comment: That worked. I was able to carefully pry the adaptors off and mount it with the adaptor I have pictured in my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The
[Seagate momentus 5400.2 ST968912A](https://www.seagate.com/support/disc/manuals/ata/100367120a.pdf)
is a
[Parallel ATA (PATA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA)
disk.

The
[Seagate momentus 4200.2 ST960821A](https://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/disc/manuals/notebook/momentus/4200.2/100342049d.pdf)
is also PATA.

This seems to be indicated by the `A` termination.
SATA disk serials seem to terminate with `AS`.

You may still be able to buy PATA interface cards or devices
if you search for them.